# Warning “attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to call a controller, if has response error, and redirect the user for login controller.

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"EventManagerStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
LoginViewController *loginController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginID"];
[loginController viewDidLoad];
loginController.showOnlyLoginForm = YES;

[self presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

and I facing this warning -

> Attempt to present Attempt to present LoginViewController: 0x7fc958201130 on ProfileController: 0x7fc9583118e0 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: I would recommend to use 'loadViewIfNeeded' instead of directly calling `viewDidLoad` callback

Comment: You should _never_ call `viewDidLoad` yourself - it's called automatically once the view controller's view is loaded

Comment: @MilanNosáľ there's no diference.

Comment: my note was regarding the call to `viewDidLoad`, it wasn't supposed to solve your problem. anyway, the error message is pretty self explanatory. your code is called when the `self` is not presented, so `self` cannot present other view controllers. but without more context, nobody will help you any better. there might be tens or hundreds reasons why that happens, but without seeing the rest of the code we can just guess.. In other words, the code you showed is OK, the problem is in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run this code in viewDidLoad try it in viewDidAppear

```
 [self presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

Edit:

use in appDelegate if you implement navigationController

```
 [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Actually I'm running in connectionDidFinishLoading

Comment: Does ProfileController is shown or where you implement connectionDidFinishLoading

Comment: I'm implement connectionDidFinishLoading on my app delegate. I force the logout of user when have some responser error.

Comment: you may implement navigation controller to accomplish this as there is not viewController in appDelegate to present your login or use notification center / delegate to tell another viewController to make the present instead of appdelegate

Comment: but your log identifies that you want to present it in a viewController named ProfileController , even self present .... will not run in app delegate

Comment: But I need get the information about user, when they open the after terminate.